# problem understanding a string pattern

Tags: java, regex, string, gwt

I'm learning GWT by following [this tutorial](http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/webtoolkit/doc/trunk/tutorial/gettingstarted.html) but there's something I don't quite fully understand in step 4. The following line's checking that a string matches a pattern:

```
    if (!str.matches("^[0-9A-Z\\.]{1,10}$")) {...}
```

After checking [the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for the Pattern class I understand that the characters ^ and $ represent the beginning and the end of the line, and that [...]{1,10} means that the part in brackets [...] has to be present at least once but not more than 10 times. What I don't understand is the final characters of the part in brackets. 0-9A-Z means a range of characters from 0 to 9 or from A to Z. But what does \\. mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It matches a dot character. Since dot has a special meaning in regexp, it must be escaped with a backslash. And because backslash has a special meaning in Java strings, it must be escaped with another backslash.

Answer (score 1):

dot .
As it is a special character in regexp syntax.
Also it has two escapes as \ is a special character in java strings.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what you're saying. Could you please explain it in any other way?

Comment: "\\." in the pattern matches "."

Answer (score 1):

It matches a dot character.  A double slash '\\' simply means a single '\' as you have to escape '\'s in java strings.  So '\\.' is translated to '\.' which means match just a '.' character.  If you just used '.' by itself, without escaping, it would match any character.  So you have to escape it, to match a '.' character.

Answer (score 1):

The dot "." in regex means "any character". An escaped dot "." (or "\.") means the dot character itself (without any special regex behaviour like the unescaped dot).

So, for example, "123.ABC" could be a line that matches the given regex (line breaks etc. not included).